# Accessing Amazon S3 via FTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

I have did a number of searches and can't seem to understand if this is doable at all.

I have a data logger that has FTP-push function. The FTP-push function have the following settings:

```
FTP server
Port
Upload directory
User name
Password
```

In general, I understand that a Filezilla client (I have a Pro edition) is able to drop files into my AWS S3 bucket and I had done this successfully in my local PC.

Is it possible to remove the Filezilla client requirement and input my S3 information directly into my data logger? Something like the below diagram:

```
Data logger ----FTP----> S3 bucket
```

If not, what will be the most sensible method to have my data logger JSON files drop into AWS S3 via FTP?

Comment: Where are the source files? Are they on an Amazon EC2 instance, or on your own computer?

Comment: The source files will be coming directly from the data logger on-site.

Comment: What is the "data logger"? Is it a computer? What device is it? If it is a 'device', how does it communicate with the outside world? Can it save to something other than FTP?

Comment: The data logger records hardware measurements - it is a proprietary hardware based on individual manufacturer. The data logger consolidate data and push to a cloud platform. I need to get this data but in its raw format in order to process it into my own platform. Data logger has internet connection. There are like around 50+ data loggers all around my country which I need to get these FTP files from.

Comment: I'm still confused about the output options for the Data Loggers. Do they _only_ output to FTP? Do they output to the manufacturer's website, or do you configure them to point to an FTP site? Can you change the settings to output in any different way? Can you point us to some documentation on the Data Logger devices?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, you'd be better off with:

- Logging to local files
- Using a schedule to copy the log files to Amazon S3 using the `aws s3 sync` command

The schedule could be triggered by cron (Linux) or a Scheduled Task (Windows).

Comment: +1 for simplicity’s sake, but also for security reasons. FTP is an old and unsecure protocol. If you can’t use SFTP or FTP/S (you can use AWS for that), you should store the files locally and upload them using a secure API, like the one S3 provides.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By logging to local files you mean to say that I should setup a hardware (e.g Raspberry Pi) and store the incoming FTP files inside the device and then do a schedule to upload to S3 via CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon did add support recently to [AWS Transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/) for FTP support. This will provide an integration with Amazon S3 via FTP without setting up any additional infrastructure, however you should review the pricing at the moment.

As an alternative you could create an intermediary server that can sync between itself and AWS S3 using the cli `aws s3 sync`.

Comment: Neat, AWS Transfer seems to be pretty expensive and running an intermediary server is more cost effective for me. Do you happen to have an online guide in regards to the set up of this intermediary server that can sync with AWS S3?

Comment: Heres a guide to setting up an FTP on a EC2 instance: https://medium.com/tensult/configure-ftp-on-aws-ec2-85b5b56b9c94. After that is done you would setup the `aws s3 sync /path/to/ftp/folders s3://bucket-name` command on a crontab: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html